# Small typeface bug in user profiles

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've mentioned this to Jin already but wanted to drop a post onto Meta to make sure it doesn't get reported in duplicate.

Check out the screencap. We've got two different fonts in play on user pages:

[image]

Comment: Also: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/587/5

Comment: Yours is better, it's got pictures to prove it! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.